# Android, Gradle: Why(second time) "gradlew build --build-cache" not finish immediately?

Tags: android, gradle

Gradle ver.: 4.1.

As resuli in file in file: "*/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*" I has the next content:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-bin.zip
```

Android Gradle plugin: "**com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3**"

In my app's **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

My steps for build my Android project:

1. Start build(from command line) by: "**gradlew build --build-cache**"
2. Result:

   *BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6m 2s, 
   412 actionable tasks: 230 executed, 182 up-to-date*
3. I'm not change anything in my project
4. Run again same command: "**gradlew build --build-cache**"
5. Result:

   *BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 38s, 
   412 actionable tasks: 148 executed, 264 up-to-date*
6. I'm not change anything in my project
7. Run again same command: "**gradlew build --build-cache**"
8. Result:

   *BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 41s, 
   412 actionable tasks: 135 executed, 277 up-to-date*

Questions:

1. Why second and third time the "**gradlew build --build-cache**" not finish immediately?
2. Why option "**--build-cache**" not help?

Comment: Still seeing the same behavior with the Android Gradle Plugin 3.0. Android libraries appear to have more tasks whose outputs are not cached as compared to Android applications, but test outputs are not cached for either applications and libraries.